# Realationship between two quadratic function

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider that $\dot{x}=Ax+bu$ where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $Q$ be a positive definite matrix and by solving the Lyapunov equation $PA+A^\top P+Q=0$,  matrix $P$, which is positive definite, is obtained. Consider that $V_1=\frac{1}{2}x^\top Px$ and $V_2=-x^\top Qx$. Is there any $\gamma>0$ such that $V_2 \leq -\gamma V_1$. If yes, how can I obtain this $\gamma$?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean $V_2=-\frac{1}{2}x^TQx$ and $V_1=x^TPx$? If so, we can prove it.

To see this, notice that $\forall x$: 
$$-\frac{1}{2}x^TQx=\frac{1}{2}x^TPAx+\frac{1}{2}x^TA^TPx\leq \sqrt{(x^TPx)(x^TAPA^Tx)}$$
where the inequality follows directly from Cauchy–Schwarz inequality. Now let $\lambda$ be the largest singular value of $A$ and notice that $\forall x$:
$$x^TAPA^Tx\leq \lambda^2x^TPx $$

Then,
$$-\frac{1}{2}x^TQx=\leq \sqrt{(x^TPx)(x^TAPA^Tx)}<|\lambda|x^TPx.$$